# Generate client-side pdf with jspdf on phonegap based apps

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jspdf

i try to generate a pdf from local datas.

I had problems with the ArrayBuffer() and the Uint8Array objects. The solution was to add a js implemention i found in the internet.

Now there is a error on this line:

`E/Web Console(21515): Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at file:///android_asset/www/libs/jspdf.js:973`

This is the line:

`blob = new Blob([array], {type: "application/pdf"});`

I added BlobBuilder.js and Blob.js (like in the jspdf example).

In general, is it possible to to that with jspdf? (i found a lot of problems with jspdf)

How can i solve this problem?

What can i do to generate pdfs on browser, android and ios..?

Thanks for help and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
try  
{
    blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
    console.debug("case 1");
}
catch (e)  
{
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
                   window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
                      window.MozBlobBuilder ||
                      window.MSBlobBuilder;
    if (e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder)  
    {
        var bb = new BlobBuilder();
        bb.append(data);
        blob = bb.getBlob("application/pdf");
        console.debug("case 2");
    }
    else if (e.name == "InvalidStateError")  
    {
         // InvalidStateError (tested on FF13 WinXP)
         blob = new Blob([array], {type: "application/pdf"});
         console.debug("case 3");
    }
    else  
    {
        // We're screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely   
        console.debug("Errore");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, I have same error, and I'm catching here 'case 2'

Answer (score 1):

Blob constructor doesn't work in android (no support for all the web browsers).
The quick solution is, use Phonegap filewriter to create PDF file. Below is the changes to **jsPDF.js** file:

```
output = function (type, options) {
            var undef, data, length, array, i, blob;
            switch (type) {
            case undef:
                return buildDocument();
            case 'save':
                if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                    if (window.URL === undefined) {
                        return API.output('dataurlnewwindow');
                    } else if (window.URL.createObjectURL === undefined) {
                        return API.output('dataurlnewwindow');
                    }
                }
                data = buildDocument();
                write(data, options);                    
                break;
            case 'datauristring':
            case 'dataurlstring':
                return 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + btoa(buildDocument());
            case 'datauri':
            case 'dataurl':
                document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + btoa(buildDocument());
                break;
            case 'dataurlnewwindow':
                window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + btoa(buildDocument()));
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error('Output type "' + type + '" is not supported.');
            }
            // @TODO: Add different output options
        };
```

Add cordova file plugin from CLI as **"cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file"** to your project.

Next implement **write()** function using phonegap filewriter API like below:

```
write = function (data, filename) {
    var PERSISTENT = window.PERSISTENT || LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT;

window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(filename, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.write(data);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Vinod, after implementing your code now i am able to download file only but with size=0. Is i am missing something. Waiting for your reply.