# Creating PDF files in PhoneGap using jsPDF

Tags: java, android, cordova, jspdf

I'm working on an phonegap android app where I need to generate a pdf file based on user input, so I choosed jsPDF to generate the pdf file.
Noting that the app when tested on a web browser it's working well, however when tested on an android emulator I got the following error :

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor at file:///android_asset/www/js/jspdf.js:973

and this is how I create my pdf file :
.
.
doc.save('Test.pdf');

Any ideas ?

Comment: Look at link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596005/generate-client-side-pdf-with-jspdf-on-phonegap-based-apps?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way to late, but you can hjack the data variable in jspdf.js at line 963 and just save that as *.pdf. It will get you the PDF file. 
But i don't think theres a realy clean way.