# Generating pdf file using sencha touch + phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, pdf-generation

I`m new to sencha touch and i`ve been searching the web,but all i found is generating pdf file using sencha only.

I want to know if its possible to generate a pdf file using sencha touch + phonegap(making it as a native app),and some help on how to do it.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Generate the PDFs in the JS using something like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) (advantage: it will work on all platforms, disadvantages: it may use lot of memory and the PDF output may still not be perfect)
2. Generate the PDFs in the PhoneGap plugin (you will probably need to create the plugin yourself, and for each platform you want to support)
3. Generate the PDFs on the server - send the data from the app there, and put just download link in the app

Answer (score 1):

in addition you will have to use this modification for the addImage to work check out the link below

[Generate client-side pdf with jspdf on phonegap based apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596005/generate-client-side-pdf-with-jspdf-on-phonegap-based-apps)

hope this helps